# Дальнейшее использование результата асинхронной функции

Tags: node.js

Читаем файл асинхронно.

```
fs.readFile('./path', function(err, file){})
```

В callback-е получаем результат. Есть необходимость производить с  содержимым файла различные манипуляции, например:

```
function addOne(file){console.log(file+'1')}
function addSmt(file, smt){console.log(file+smt)}
```

Другими словами, файл надо прочитать один и только один раз, а потом работать с его содержимым по мере надобности.

Comment: Так работайте. Кто запрёщает? Или Вы о том, что работать с файлом надо вне callback'а? Тогда сохраняйте файл в какой-нибудь глобальной переменной.

Comment: О глобальной переменной я и сам подумывал, но как то не по ГОСТу оно. Тут вся сложность в том, что бы читать файл только один раз, а не при каждом вызове addOne к примеру. И даже если так:

var globVar = '';\n
fs.readFile(path, f(err, file){globVar=file});\n
addOne(globVar);\n

Как заставить addOne() дождаться globVar?

Comment: Не очень понятно, что именно Вы хотите. Но, возможно, Вам следует заменить fs.readFile на её синхронного брата fs.readFileSync

Comment: Что то не выходит мысль сформулировать). fs.readFile я использовал для примера. В проекте будет MongoClient, который возвращает объект базы данных так же, как и fs.readFile возвращает file. То есть мне надо создать коннект один раз, а потом уже работать с тем, что вернул callback и синхронного варианта в документации я не нашел.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Буду использовать глобальную переменную, а дожидаться через settimeout, что правда, по моему, есмь костыль)))

Comment: @alexandrr Посмотрите wait.for (ссылка есть в http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844450/wait-for-an-async-function-to-return-in-node-js )