# Оцените функцию

Tags: node.js

При изучении nodejs передо мной стала задача - выполнить асинхронную функцию и работать с ее результатом вне callback-а. [Тут мне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/269084/node-js-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#) посоветовали записать результат в глобальную переменную. Пойдя по этому пути я написал следующее:

```
function checker (val, callback) {
  if (checker[val]) {
    callback(checker[val]);
  } else {
    setImmediate(function(){
      checker(val, callback);
    });
  }
}

fs.readFile('./smt.txt', 'utf-8', function (err, file) {
  checker.file = file;  
});

checker('file', function (file){
  console.log(file);
})
```

Тут при выполнении callback-а мы записываем ожидаемую переменную в свойство функции checker (лучше названия не придумал) и, при необходимости что то сделать с переменной, вызываем checker передав ей имя переменной и callback для работы с ней.
Хочу услышать ваше мнение и конструктивную критику об этом подходе.

Comment: [Нормальный вариант функции checker.](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#memoize)

Answer (score 1):

Для таких задач придуманы [Promises/A+](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/), то что вы придумали, хм, ну я даже не знаю, это какой-то индусский код получается.

Материалы по теме:

- [Promise – это не больно](http://www.slideshare.net/yandex/02-25806903)
- [Promises + NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351494/promises-pattern-in-node-js-libraries-to-use)
- [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), [When](https://github.com/cujojs/when/wiki) и т.п.

Comment: Сейчас я хочу разобраться с нодой, с тем что я могу сделать с ней без библиотек (шаблонизаторы и базы данных не в счет).  По сути, мне пока нужно только решить задачу, которую я, как мог, описал в вопросе. Можете показать как должно красиво выглядеть ее решение без использования библиотек?

Comment: Красивое решение, это понять что такое Promises/A+. Можно набросать для понимния [маленький пример][1], потом удалить его и взять библиотеку для работы с Promises/Defer — вот это будет очень красивое и правильное решение.

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/VwCfw/